# Connection pool with single connection vs connection for infrequent queries

Tags: java, sql, connection-pooling

I am building a Java application which queries my SQL server once a minute. Right now, the application is using a connection pool with a single connection (min pool size 1, max pool size 1).

I figured that a pool size of 1 would be enough because of the infrequent queries (once a minute, as mentioned before).

Do I need a connection pool at all, and if the answer is yes, is 1 connection enough? Or should I just not use a pool and open a new connection every minute?

Comment: If you already have the pool set up, what are you hoping to achieve by removing it?

Comment: @Kayaman Efficiency and pefromance improvements and future knowledge.

Comment: Do you really think your efficiency and performance will improve in any noticeable way? (Hint: it won't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using a connection pool with a single connection (min pool size 1, max
>   pool size 1).

In such case don't see any need or benefit of using connection pool since at any point in time there will be only one connection object and if it's in use then other request has to wait (or) create a non-pooled connection object.

Connection pooling is generally used to save time/resource from creation/tearing-up the connection object.

In your specific case, you can probably create a connection instance and dispose it off once done with your work.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give some reason to use the connection pool, potentially with multiple connections. Not sure if you are considering this negative case.

In real world, a query might run more than 1 minute with various reason. 
Do you want the application to wait for the hung connection? Or what is your expected behavior for this?

Also if you use connection pool, DB connection initialize process(time and resource consuming) is done while the pool is generated. When you actually use the DB connection pool, some of initialization step should be already done so it reduce repetitive overhead when the application is running query.

Comment: Would be fine for it to just hang it that case.

Comment: @XLordalX It depends on the behavior you want. If it hung, that means the application stops doing its work and have to restart the app

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing the database that rarely, then in practice having a connection pool will not provide any significant benefit. However, I'd keep it if it's already written. Maybe one day your application will grow and you'll find the pool useful. It's not a bad thing to have.